# Can't add value to MySql database with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add a value to my DB with PHP without success. I did it with some fields but for some reason this one is not working.

Input: "Project"

I'm a beginner in PDO coding, and I cannot get out of there.

HTML:

```
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="Event 1" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <input type="text" name="project" id="project" value="projectPA" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea name="description" id="description" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></textarea>
            <label for="start_date">Start</label>
            <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>"
                   class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <label for="end_date">End</label>
            <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date"
                   value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + 3600); ?>"
                   class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

            <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
            <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
use QuickPdo\QuickPdo;
use Tim\TimServer\TimServer;
use Tim\TimServer\TimServerInterface;

require_once __DIR__ . "/../../init.php";

TimServer::create()->start(function (TimServerInterface $server) {
if (
    isset($_POST['title']) &&
    isset($_POST['description']) &&
    isset($_POST['start_date']) &&
    isset($_POST['end_date'])
) {
    if (false !== $id = QuickPdo::insert('the_events', [
            'title' => $_POST['title'],
            'description' => $_POST['description'],
            'start_date' => $_POST['start_date'],
            'end_date' => $_POST['end_date'],
            'project' => $_POST['project'],
        ])
    ) {
        $server->success($id);
    }
    else {
        appLog("[app]/www/service/insert-event: pdo error: {pdoError}", [
            'pdoError' => QuickPdo::getLastError(),
        ]);
        $server->error('An error occurred with the database, please retry 
 later.');
    }

}
})->output();
```

Comment: It's probably more opinion, but if "PDO" is more of a reference to prepared statements, it's much better to learn it "raw".  It's quite straightfoward as-is, whereas that 'QuickPDO' framework looks to me like it offers no real benefits to learning, and just obfuscates the entire learning process.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Nothing at all. They all are working but I cannot add a new one since it crash. There's a way to debug it?

Comment: I suggest adding an `else` clause for the `if` where you test if everything isset. That will tell you if you have received form data at all.

Comment: And of course general PHP troubleshooting advice: if you get *nothing*, as in a completely white screen in your browser, it's probably a fatal PHP error. You should check your http server's error log. In fact, I just open a terminal window and run `tail -f` on the http server error log all the time while developing.

Comment: I'm with Chris J here. Those training wheels on PDO are probably part of the problem. Get rid of them, learn to use PDO directly and effectively, and your code will be *instantly* more understandable to the PHP community, which is imporatant when coming here and looking for answers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Will you take POST data? Default form method is GET and you check POST array? Maybe its problem?

Comment: Not understand.